# how to make JDialog inactive

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

I want to make JDialog-based window inactive, so all controls apeared disabled (in grey color). setEnabled(false) just makes impossible to click any control, even close window. But nothing turns gray. Help please.

**EDIT**: Here is sample code.

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;


public class Analyzer extends JDialog{

public Analyzer() {
    JButton but = new JButton("test");
    setLayout(null);
    but.setBounds(10,10,100,100);

    add(but);
    setSize( 200, 200);
    setVisible(true);
    setEnabled(false);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Analyzer();
}

}
```

Comment: code sample added. Do You say that i need to iterate through all controls and disable them manually?

Comment: That's not quite the sample we're looking for. We'd like to see your attempt to solve this. Have you considered using recursion to recurse through the container/component tree of the JDialog, enabling or disabling all components found?

Comment: I agree with Hovercraft... setDisabled on each component the JDialog contains.

Comment: yes, i'm considering this kind of solution but it seems to messy. Maybe there is preffered way to do this?

Comment: fixed sample to what i've tried

Comment: How messy can it be as it's only a few lines of code.

Comment: Messy is wrong word. Сlumsy may be more correct.

Comment: Calling `setEnabled(false)` on the dialog should disable it, but it won't be movable, and it's buttons and components will still "look" enabled.

Comment: Thanks everybody. Decided not to waste time. Using iteration through components.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: this is what i mentioned in question =)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The two ways I know to do this, one where you disable the components of a dialog recursively, and the second where you disable the entire dialog (including ability to drag the dialog):

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class DisableEg extends JPanel {
   public static final String DISABLE_DIALOG_COMPONENTS = "Disable Dialog Components";
   public static final String ENABLE_DIALOG_COMPONENTS = "Enable Dialog Components";
   public static final String DISABLE_DIALOG = "Disable Dialog";
   public static final String ENABLE_DIALOG = "Enable Dialog";
   private static final int LOC_SHIFT = 150;
   private Analyzer analyzer;

   public DisableEg(JFrame frame) {
      analyzer = new Analyzer(frame);
      analyzer.pack();
      analyzer.setLocationRelativeTo(frame);
      Point location = analyzer.getLocation();
      location = new Point(location.x - LOC_SHIFT, location.y - LOC_SHIFT);
      analyzer.setLocation(location);
      analyzer.setVisible(true);

      add(new JButton(new AbstractAction(DISABLE_DIALOG_COMPONENTS) {

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            AbstractButton btn = (AbstractButton) evt.getSource();
            if (btn.getText().equals(DISABLE_DIALOG_COMPONENTS)) {
               btn.setText(ENABLE_DIALOG_COMPONENTS);
               analyzer.setComponentEnabled(false);
            } else {
               btn.setText(DISABLE_DIALOG_COMPONENTS);
               analyzer.setComponentEnabled(true);
            }
         }
      }));
      add(new JButton(new AbstractAction(DISABLE_DIALOG) {

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            AbstractButton btn = (AbstractButton) evt.getSource();
            if (btn.getText().equals(DISABLE_DIALOG)) {
               btn.setText(ENABLE_DIALOG);
               analyzer.setEnabled(false);
            } else {
               btn.setText(DISABLE_DIALOG);
               analyzer.setEnabled(true);
            }
         }
      }));
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Disable Example");
      DisableEg mainPanel = new DisableEg(frame);

      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class Analyzer extends JDialog {

   public Analyzer(JFrame frame) {
      super(frame, "Analyzer Dialog", false);
      JButton but = new JButton("test");
      setLayout(new FlowLayout());

      add(but);
      setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
   }

   public void setComponentEnabled(boolean enabled) {
      setComponentEnabled(enabled, getContentPane());

      // !! if you have menus to disable, you may need instead
      // setComponentEnabled(enabled, this); // !!
   }

   private void setComponentEnabled(boolean enabled, Component component) {
      component.setEnabled(enabled);
      if (component instanceof Container) {
         Component[] components = ((Container) component).getComponents();
         if (components != null && components.length > 0) {
            for (Component heldComponent : components) {
               setComponentEnabled(enabled, heldComponent);
            }
         }
      }
   }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

The typical way to do this is to use a glassPane, but Java 7 introduced JLayer that should do the trick too.

Comment: If I'm reading the OP's question correctly, this won't work as he wants the components to display a disabled appearance. AFAIK, the typical way to do this is to use recursion.

Comment: this way is more than confortable, GlassPane could be Colored, so simple and not accesible by Mouse, nice thread  +1 for both (@Pete great code ++++++++)